# Updated isolated scope on multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a ng-repeat creating multiple directives, each with an isolated scope. I want to be able to call a single function that calls a function on each directive, so it resets a variable on each isolated scope. I can't work out anyway to do this? I realise this might not be best practice, but I just need a solution at the moment.

Comment: post your code and show us what all you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that i use in a similar vein is angulars event system.

I'm creating a dashboard of widgets. My widget is a directive contained within a `ng-repeat`.

I emit events in my controller `$scope.$broadcast` then listen in my directive with `$scope.$on`. I use the `$index` of the `ng-repeat` to be able to target specific widgets.

quick example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adyjm9g4/

EDIT: Forgot to mention you can also pass data: http://jsfiddle.net/adyjm9g4/1/

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it is to provide a callback to the directive (i.e. `scope: { xxx: '&' }`) that will execute some functionality. Could be:

```
<the-directive callback="ctrl.command(action, argument)" />
```

And the directive looks like:

```
app.directive('theDirective', function() {
    return {
        ...
        scope: {
            callback: '&',
            ...
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            this.resetTheVariable = function() {
                // DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE
            };

            $scope.callback({ action: 'register', argument: this });

            $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                scope.callback({ action: 'deregister', argument: this });
            });
        }]
    };
})
```

Now the controller invoking this directive would look like:

```
function TheController() {
    var registeredDirectives = [];

    this.command = function(action, argument) {
        switch(action) {
            case 'register':
                registeredDirectives.push(argument);
                break;
            case 'deregister':
                var index = registeredDirectives.indexOf(argument);
                if( index >= 0 ) {
                    registeredDirectives.splice(index, 1);
                }
                break;
        }
    };

    this.resetAll = function() {
        registeredDirectives.forEach(function(registeredDirectiveController) {
            registeredDirectiveController.resetTheVariable();
        });
    };
}
```